# Center content in middle column using only HTML

Tags: html

I don't know if this is even the right way of asking this or if it's even possible with only HTML.  I'm using a review platform called feedbackwhiz and they have a template editor but it only allows you to input HTML (as far as I understand).  I'm trying to emulate Amazon's email structure where all of their content is left justified in the center column with a column to either side of just white space.

**Amazon email example**

[image: Amazon email example]

**The HTML editor**

[image: HTML editor from feedbackwhiz]

So essentially I want to put my content of the email, left justified in the center column, similar to the attached Amazon image, using the HTML editor I have.  Is that possible?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzpuJ.jpg):

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the kind of thing CSS is for. You could inline it if you can't use an external css file. try this:

```
<div style="margin:auto;flex-flow:row wrap;width:100px;background-color:red;display:flex;text-align:left;">
  <input type="button" value="clickme" />
  <p>some texttttt</p>
  <p>some texttttt moreeeee</p>
</div>
```

demo example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PaqKOL?&editors=101

reference material: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/